# RJS in Play Framework

Tags: java, javascript, playframework, rjs

have anyone found a substitution for RJS in "Ruby on Rails" for play?

P.S.
I don't mean just a tag with script section.
I mean real server-generated JavaScript-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in Play yet. In the roadmap of Scala-version of Play they mentioned that they wanted to add this, the way Lift does it.

But right now, *no, there is none*.